# Kobold2d - ARC issues when I restart xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, static-libraries, kobold2d

I added kobold2d libcocosdenshion-ios.a static library to my workspace with my project. Everything works fine but I restarted xcode and I got LOT of ARC errors! 30sec before everything works perfect? I don't delete line of code. Anyone has such a problem? What happened?

[image]

Comment: You don't say whether they are actual code errors or mistaken reports.

Comment: @Phillip Mills I got lot of ARC Restrictions errors from CocosDenshion.m and CDAudioManager.m

Comment: @PhillipMills please check my updated question with picture

Comment: You don't have to do this in Kobold2D, CocosDenshion is already added as a library to all Kobold2D projects. It looks like you dropped the CD source code into your project (target), which won't work because CD is not ARC code.

Comment: @PhillipMills I'm not working in Kobolod2d project but in my ARC regular xcode project. I just want to use CocosDenshion, SimpleAudioUnit in my project for audio handling. So I dragged folder called CocosDenshion to my regular porject because if I only added static library to my link library autocomplete doesnt find headers :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're linking to a .a file that contains the binary for the classes you want, then there's no need for the matching .m files.  The library plus any headers should be all you need for building your own app.

Comment: SO I've to delete all .m from folder CocosDneshion in my main project?

Comment: yes, that should work - assuming the headers in the folder match the archive file

Comment: YES! It works. Going to write step by step tutorial because I spent 3 days on it...